# Why is the NetworkIdentity component making my Game Object invisible? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently trying to make a multiplayer snake game, I have never made a multiplayer game before. I am having a very strange issue where whenever I add the NetworkIdentity component to my 'Snake' game object, it becomes invisible, but is still there. The game is still functional; you just can't see the snake.

I have two pictures attached, one is the game with the NetworkIdentity component, one is the game without it. Thank you for the help.

[Without component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNzXA.png)

[With component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTble.png)

Answer (score 0):

A) your image labels seem to be flipped .. exchange the `Without` and `With` ;)

and B) Afaik this is the expected behavior for any `GameObject` with a `NetworkIdentity` as long as you are not connected to any network yet. It will get enabled once you host or join a session.

You probably would rather convert this into the [player prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetPlayers.html) though and not have it in your scene from the beginning but rather let the NetworkManager automatically spawn it for every player in the session including yourself.

Comment: Thank you derHugo! Ended up figuring it out, much appreciated. And yeah once I just hosted a session and made the snake game object the player prefab it worked perfectly